# WCf Return Data, convert into Datatable in c#

Tags: json, wcf, datatable

Here is My Response

```
[
  {
    "Response": [
      {
        "TypeId": "1",
        "TypeName": "Wastage not collected"
      },
      {
        "TypeId": "2",
        "TypeName": "Drainage not cleaned"
      },
      {
        "TypeId": "3",
        "TypeName": "Dispose dead animal"
      },
      {
        "TypeId": "4",
        "TypeName": "Sweeper Misbehaviour"
      },
      {
        "TypeId": "5",
        "TypeName": "Water supply issue"
      },
      {
        "TypeId": "6",
        "TypeName": "Wastage burning issue"
      },
      {
        "TypeId": "7",
        "TypeName": "Others"
      }
    ],
    "Status": "Ok"
  }
]
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is a JSON string. You'll find a lot of duplicate questions that show how to parse JSON data

Comment: It is recommanded that you use List<T> as the return result instead of Datatable.